# Cant make the toolbar wrap correctly

Tags: android, toolbar

I am trying to make the toolbar fit correctly and have no top or side edges and I am not getting it, any idea how to get it?
I have tried changing the insets from the java code but it has not worked either.
I've been stuck for days and can't find a solution, help!
Here is the xml of the toolbar

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:elevation="6dp"
    app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    android:titleMargin="0dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageViewPerfilMensajesPrivados"
            android:layout_width="67dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/user" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/nombre"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="RECEPTOR" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:textColor="#fff"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="RECEPTOR" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>
```

And here the Java code

```
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.mCustomToolbar);
        toolbar.setContentInsetsRelative(0,0);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
```

And this is how it looks like right now.
[image]

Comment: Post the entire layout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is not in this toolbar layout, issue is in the layout of activity or fragment. The top container in your activity/fragment has padding or there is a margin in the container(that has a list ) of toolbar layout if there's any container.

Possible solutions:

1. Remove the padding from the container that has the toolbar (if toolbar is being included as an independent view).
2. Or remove margin from the container that has the toolbar or most likely place the toolbar as a top most child.